# Defining OR Condition with grails criteria api

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have the following domain objects:

```
class User {
    String name
    Transaction transaction

    static constraints = {
        transaction nullable: true
    }
}

class Transaction {        
    boolean successful
    User user        
    static belongsTo = User
}
```

I want to select all `users` that have no successful transaction. This means I want the users without any transaction (`transaction == null`) and the users that have a transaction with the successful value `false` (`transaction.successful == false`). I want to do this with the Criteria API (because this can be combined with other conditions based on user input).

I tried this:

```
def c = User.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    or {
        isNull 'transaction'
        transaction {
            eq 'successful', false
        }
    }
}
```

However this gives me only the users that have a transaction (with the successful value `false`). But I do not get the users where transaction is `null`

The following code shows how I created some sample data:

```
def createUserAndTransaction(String name, Boolean successful = null) {
    User u = new User(name: name)
    if (successful != null) {
        Transaction t = new Transaction(user: u, successful: successful)
        u.setTransaction(t)
    }
    u.save()
}

def init = { servletContext ->
    createUserAndTransaction 'john', true
    createUserAndTransaction 'mike', false
    createUserAndTransaction 'pablo'
}
```

My criteria query only returns `mike` in this case. But I want `mike` and `pablo`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem is that it defaults to an inner join. You have to create an alias for the table and define its join type:

```
createAlias("transaction", "t", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

or {
    isNull("t")
    eq("t.successful", false)
}
```